# How to get toolbar of ALV CLASSIC in ALV with IDA?

Tags: alv, cds

I am programing a CDS VIEW using ALV with IDA, but I have a question..
how to add toolbar of ALV classic in ALV IDA, especically the layout buttons?

[image: View Image Please]

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! Give more explanation about problem and be clear to explanation.

Comment: Hi.
My problem is the toolbar of ALV IDA.
How can I make the classic ALV toolbar appear in my ALV IDA?
See attached image.

Comment: What is IDA????